# Is it possible to use NOGAPPS and Maps API with Uber app (or apps similar to Uber)?

Tags: lineageos

I have installed LineageOS 14.1 on a Wingtech 88047 (Redmi 2 Pro), without Gapps. I installed microG UnifiedNlp, and my phone finds its location correctly. I also tested some proprietary apps that I need (mostly bank apps), and they do work perfectly. However, I cannot use apps that need the Maps API.
For example, neither the Uber app nor an app by on of their competitors in Brazil will work (the app opens, but gets stuck and doesn't show the map).

I do have  [NOGAPPS](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1715375) version of Maps API installed (version 0.5, which is the only release available [from Github](https://github.com/mar-v-in/MapsAPI/releases/). But maybe there is an updated version? It seems that version 0.5 only covers MAPS API v.1, not v.2.

So -- is there any way to get apps like those (which need MAPS api) without installing Gapps?

Comment: Have you only installed UnifiedNLP? If so, uninstall it and install *microG GmsCore* (which includes UnifiedNLP, but also Maps API v2). It's available via the [microG F-Droid repository](https://microg.org/fdroid.html), or alternatively directly [from their Github page](https://github.com/microg/android_packages_apps_GmsCore/releases). Instructions can be found [in their wiki](https://github.com/microg/android_packages_apps_GmsCore/wiki).

Comment: Thank you! I installed UnifiedNLP and flashed NetworkLocation.apk mapsapi.flashable.zip. Do I need to remove those? How woudl I do that?

Comment: I suppose it's better to reflash the ROM and start over?

Comment: I'd start removing them before installing according to the instructions. Don't know why you flashed the old NetworkLocation.apk (I've never flashed that, even in the old days of NOGAPPS) – but it probably only placed the `.apk` file into `/system/apps-priv` or the like; so removing the file and rebooting the device should take care for that. Let the Maps APIv1 remain for apps needing it (there are some), as µG only ships with v2. Of course, starting with a clean ROM makes sure there're no conflicts and thus is the best approach, if that's an option for you ;)

Comment: Hm. IT seems that microG GsmCore needs Signature Spoofing. I have the Xposed installer working, but when I try to insatll it warns me that Xposed is not yet compatible with my CPU/architecture (armeabi-v7a). And also that it cannot link `/data/user/0/de.robv.android.xposed.installer/cache/app_process` because `libdvm.so` wasn't found.

Comment: Used Tingle, and it worked perfectly. Now I have signature spoofing (verified) and got microG Gsm core installed. Did all as per the instructions (except that I did not install Blankstore, since I already have Yalp). But the apps which use maps still don't work.

Comment: Isn't LOS 14 Android 7? XPosed doesn't (yet?) work with Nougat. But glad you found a solution! Mind to [answer your own question](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) then, with a step-by-step guide? As for Blankstore: I recommend to at least install Fakestore then – at least when the first app starts complaining it needs Google Services (that's what Fakestore is for, nothing more: making apps believe Playstore would be there).

Comment: * Yes, LOS is Android 7. Anyway -- actually, I got signature spoofing and installation of microG GsmCore, but the apps don't work yet. One of them used to complain that it "won't work without Google Services"; now, with FakeStore, it complains that I "need to update Google Services" :-)  Anyway, I'm not sure this will work... I'll fiddle a bit more with it, but without much hope.

Comment: I'm running a similar installation for years now. The only apps (from those I use) that didn't work where those wanting to verify their license via Playstore (neither Fakestore, nor Blankstore support that, and Yalp cannot as it doesn't claim it were Playstore (package name). Not sure what maybe your app is needing that's not implemented in µG – somethings are not yet in there, others (like ads/analytics) never will be.

Answer (score 2):

You need FakeStore for microG to be detected correctly and a recent version of [microG GmsCore](https://microg.org/download.html) (you need to use the drop-down menu).

Check that you have at least the version 0.2.4-103 of microG GmsCore.